# How to find out the transfer function of a FIR filter?

Tags: filters, z-transform, transfer-function, finite-impulse-response

$$h[n]=\begin{cases}a^n & \text{if } 0 \le n < N \\
0 & \text{otherwise}\end{cases}$$
And for which values of $a$ the filter is stable

I know that the transfer function will be

$$H(z)=\frac{z}{z-a}~,~|z|>a$$

how to find out the values of $a$ for it's stability ?

Comment: what happened to $N$?  why does not $N$ appear as a parameter in your transfer function?

Comment: i might be wrong then @robertbristow-johnson

Comment: your $h[n]$ **is** an FIR. and FIRs are always stable (at least if implemented the straight-forward way).  but the transfer function $H(z)$ is that of an IIR, which is what happens to your $h[n]$ if you allow $N \to \infty$ .

Comment: you can use the finite geometric summation series: $$ \sum\limits_{n=0}^{N-1} x^n = \frac{1 - x^N}{1-x} $$ to obtain your transfer function.

Comment: how do you know that is the transfer function? that is the Z-transform of $a^n \cdot u[n]$, but $h[n] = a^n \cdot (u[n] - u[n-N])$

Comment: @oxuf, that was the main point i was trying to gently tell the OP.  and i had to correct a general statement that "FIRs are always stable".  **this particular FIR** can be implemented as a tail-cancelling IIR (also called *Truncated* IIR filters or **TIIR**), in a manner similar to the *moving-average filter*.  then, even though the result is FIR, internal stability can be an issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

\begin{align}
y[n] &= h[n]  * x[n]\\
&= h[0]x[n] + h[1]x[n-1] + \ldots + h[N-2]x[n-(N-2)] + h[N-1]x[n-(N-1)]\\
&= a^{0}x[n] +a^{1}x[n-1] + \ldots + a^{N-2} x[n-(N-2)] + a^{N-1} x[n-(N-1)]
\end{align}
So

$$\mathcal Z\{y[n]\} = Y(z) = X(z)\left(1 + az^{-1} + ... + a^{N-2}z^{-(N-2)} + a^{N-1}z^{-(N-1)}\right)$$

and

$$H(z) = \dfrac{Y(z)}{X(z)} = 1 + az^{-1} + ... + a^{N-2}z^{-(N-2)} + a^{N-1}z^{-(N-1)}$$

For $a$ finite, $H(z)$ is finite and thus stable for finite input values.